# Make downvotes free when downvoter leaves a comment?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, downvote-reason

I posted a question, and it got downvoted within seconds with no comment.  Was my question a terrible one or violating the FAQ? I didn't think so when I asked it, and I only asked it after an honest effort to find the answer in the documentation of the library I'm using.

I'm not mad that I was downvoted. Maybe there is some perspective I didn't have, and my question was indeed a poor-quality question. But there really isn't a way for me to know because the downvoter simply downvoted and moved along.

Basically I'm posting now because I'm wondering, **would it make sense to make downvotes free if the downvoter leaves a comment on why they're downvoting?** This way people are incentivized to give feedback which improves the user experience and trains them to produce better quality posts in the future.

Please realize that this question is unlike a lot of similar posts on the topic for the following reasons:

1. I am *not* suggesting we force people to leave comments. They could still downvote and lose their reputation points if they choose to. Downvotes as they are today would continue unimpeded.
2. I am making it easier for people who want to downvote, but I don't want to lose the reputation points. If anything, this will encourage **more downvotes**.

Comment: and what about downvoting the question and upvoting an existing comment on that?

Comment: I actually think this is a superior idea to the constant "require downvotes" idea. Still seems prone to abuse as Servy's comment shows. Also, downvotes on questions are *always* free.

Comment: Remember you civics class.  The right to not disclose why you voted is a self-evident and unalienable right in a democracy.  Such a right cannot be surrendered in a social contract, that corrupts the system.

Comment: @HansPassant - unfortunately you're only considering the voting for elected officials - the votes cast by those officials (arguably much more important) are public in most cases for very important reasons.  And, again, I'm not trying to change current downvotes.  I'm simply suggesting a way to provide an incentive for someone to take the time to leave constructive criticism.

Comment: @Louis - yes, I would say that is a dupe.  I did make an effort to find anything which may have covered this topic.  I'll close it out.

Comment: You're talking about a downvote on your question, but downvotes on questions are *already* free.

Answer (score 9):

Also, you only lose 1 reputation when downvoting an **answer**.  Downvotes on questions are already free.

Comment: You're right - that is a good point I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 5):

You're right that this is different from the typical "force people to leave down-votes" requests but it still doesn't get around the problem of people leaving nonsense comments. How does it help anyone if someone comments "aldkjfalsdjfa;d" after down-voting? How would we prevent it *without* increasing the moderation load on the site?

I still don't see this resulting in anything other than more noise that has to get dealt with.

Comment: You're absolutely right that it wouldn't - but even in that case it forces the downvoter to sacrifice their anonymity so you would at least know if you were downvoted by someone who knew what they were talking about.

Comment: @Dave So why is that a good thing?  We *want* downvotes to be anonymous.  We *don't* want them to lose their anonymity.  And then there's all the times that someone only downvotes, and someone else comments to explain without downvoting, and the author assumes the commentor downvoted.  It'd make those types of situations far more likely.

Comment: @Dave - Anonymous voting is not a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: @servy - it would be easier to accept a downvote and you'd be quicker to accept a downvote and, as a user, you'd be more likely to internalize it properly if you knew the downvoter was more reputable than most users.

Comment: @Dave but we shouldn't look at the poster, but the post itself.... why should it be different for comments?

Comment: @Dave I don't see why that'd be the case at all.  Anecdotally, I don't see users who know (or think they know) who downvoted them accepting the downvotes as being valid criticisms any more than those who don't have any idea who vote don their post.

Comment: At @BSMP - I'm not trying to solve anonymous voting and, like you, I don't think it is even a problem.  Just suggesting an incentive for people to leave proactive criticism (or, at the very least out themselves).

Comment: @Dave you specifically stated in your first comment to this answer that this is going to be reducing anonymity, and seem to feel that that is somehow a good thing, or a goal of the request.  If you don't think that anonymity is a problem, then why are you proposing a feature that tries so hard to get rid of it?

Comment: @Servy Why do you love to anonym downvoting? Your profile the same. No one can know anything of you. But you downvote (anytime) anybody if you think so. Without any explanation. If you reduces anybody reputation, the minimum to explain the reason.

Comment: @TheBitman Since you don't have much of any experience with the site, you clearly aren't familiar with what actually happens when people comment when downvoting.  It typically makes things worse, and rather rarely ends up creating constructive discussions.  The drama and problems it causes tends to be rather significant.  And that's currently happening only with people that choose to comment; what do you think would happen if you started requiring it, or heavily incentivising it?  It would either make those problems *much* worse, or prevent people from downvoting bad content (or both).

Comment: @Servy But you can understand the initial raising : how the poster correct his/hes question if s/he has no information about the ideas behind the downvote(s)?

Comment: @TheBitman The vast majority of people don't correct their posts even when they *are* told what's wrong with it.  And anyway, the purpose of the downvote is to provide feedback on the quality of the post.  If the author uses that feedback to improve the post, that's great, but the downvote is accomplishing its primary function regardless, namely informing future readers of the quality of the post.

Comment: I think the correct way for downvoting : (1) leave a comment. (2) if the owner of the question does not correct/not answer appropriately, the downvote is right.

Comment: OK. But as many good quality post as possible is the interest of everybody. And the good quality comments can promote this goal.

Comment: The only point I see here is the "asfgasv" response to a required comment for down vote. I do believe that it may be partly mitigated by not allowing down votes on questions where the down voter has not earned enough rep on a tag attached to the question. I don't want to point to moderator abuse or reviewer abuse, but blatantly flying through questions down voting does no good in helping to improve question quality. One could argue that the down vote is acting to that end, but I just read on similar post, a question was closed in less than 2 mins and never made it to triage. Not good.

Comment: @htm11h I don't need rep on a specific tag to be able to tell that something is a blatant recommendation request, or a customer support question, etc.

Comment: @BSMP those are not arguments for down votes, but valid reasons to close. The issue was down voting on question quality, not inappropriate content.

Comment: @htm11h The tooltip says *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. That applies to most of the flag reasons.

Comment: @BSMP your changing your position, "able to tell that something is a blatant recommendation request, or a customer support question" is not the same as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."  Please understand that there are a number of users on this site that would prefer to see movement to allow the OP to improve a question, allowing blatant down vote AND Close vote at the same time with ZERO feedback, is simply counter productive to improving question quality. Even a canned message would improve the current state of affairs.

Comment: *your changing your position* @htm11h No, we just disagree over whether a question being a recommendation request makes it not useful.

Comment: @BSMP this has nothing to do with specifically with a "recommendation request", the issue being addressed is "improving question quality", and possibly not allowing a down vote and close vote with no feedback (simultaneously). The exception here, to this argument is the "recommendation request", "advertising", and other such issues you raised earlier which are clearly CLOSE posts. In which case there is no need for a down vote. There is a distinction.

Comment: If you want to be anonymous, don't post the comment, but in this case you will lose a score of your reputation.

Comment: @anton_rh - How do you stop people from commenting with nonsense just to avoid the hit to their reputation?

Comment: @BSMP, people usually will not do this. If someone does this, their downvote is the same nonsense as their comment. So how do you stop people from downvoting without a reason? If someone downvotes and posts nonsense, it means their downvote is dishonest. And because of their comment, that becomes obvious. It's much better than just silent dishonest downvote (IMO).